# Show css depending on activity type in BuddyPress activity-loop

Tags: php, functions, loop, buddypress

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to show specific styles to the activity loop depending on the activity type?

This is what I had an idea of:

```
function mycustom_act_type() {
if ('friendship_created' != bp_get_activity_type() )
echo ' style="background:red;" ';
}
```

and this is in the `<li>` whithin the loop:

```
<li <?php mycustom_act_type()?> >blah </li>
```

but obviously doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://testbp.org/activity/, that activity feed has classes on each list item indicating the activity type. If you can look at that theme, I suspect you'll find the code to add the right class for your styles.